# Почему вместе не работает update и destroy? И почему если назовешь их по другому, также не отрабатывают? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Когда по отдельности вызываю эти функции отрабатывают без проблем, но когда вместе работает только update.

```
  public function update($cat,$id){
            $comm = Comments::findOrFail($id);
            $comm->update(['like'=> $comm->like + 1]);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        public function destroy($cat,$id){

            $comm = Comments::findOrFail($id);
            $comm->update(['like'=> $comm->like - 1]);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

При такой записи ругается что не видит метод update.

```
      Route::get('/article/{numb}/{id}', 'ArticlePage@update')->name('update');
        Route::get('/article/{numb}/{idk}', 'ArticlePage@destroy')->name('destroy');
```

Вызов из blade.

```
    <ul class="icons">
                <li><a href="{{route('news.update', [$new->id,$comm->id])}}"><span class="label"></span></a></li>
                <li>{{ $comm->like}} </li>
                <li><a href="{{route('news.destroy', [$new->id,$comm->id])}}" ><span class="label"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: В route нужно писать адрес контроллера, который будет обрабатывать вызов. У вас ArticlePage это контроллер или модель? Так же в blade пишите {{route('news.... тут то же самое, должен быть контроллер и путь к его функции обработки.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, да это контроллер

Comment: Попробуйте <?= action('ArticlePage@update', ['cat' => $new->id, 'id' => $comm->id]); ?> вместо bladе. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#urls)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, даже при указании полного пути <?= action('App\Http\Controllers\News\ArticlePage@update', ['cat' => $new->id, 'id' => $comm->id]); ?>  Action App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\News\ArticlePage@update not defined.

Comment: namespace не нужны для routing, он определится при автозагрузке. Вам будет проще взять сущ. пример с документации и следовать ему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас куча ошибок в роутах:

1) Неймспейс по умолчанию он `App\Http\Controllers`, то есть в вашем случае нужно указать: `News\ArticlePage`

2) Я так понял у вас `Route::group` с префиксом `news`, если нет тогда `name` указан не верно.

3) У вас не работают `update`, `destroy` потому что у вас путь идентичный `/article/{numb}/{id}`, нужно сделать разные.

В итоге если исправить все ошибки должно получиться следующее:

```
Route::get('/article/{numb}/{id}', 'News\ArticlePage@update')->name('news.update');
Route::get('/article/{numb}/{id}/destroy', 'News\ArticlePage@destroy')->name('news.destroy');
```

Comment: Cпасибо, проблема действительно была в из-за идентичных путей)